# import with AvS_FastSimpleImport and base_price Module

Tags: extensions, importexport

The Baseprice Module provides this fields: `base_price_amount`, `base_price_base_amount`, `base_price_base_unit` and `base_price_unit`.

On import procedure with `avs_fastsimpleimport`, all the other fields (`sku`, `name`, `price` ...) are correctly processed.
The fields for `base_price` are ignored.
Why?

My Import-Array shows like this:

```
$artData[] = array( 
'sku' => $line[0],
'_type' => 'simple',
'_attribute_set' => 'Default',
'_product_websites' => 'base',
'_category' => $cat_det[0]['entity_id'],
'name' => $artBez,
'price' => $price,
 ...   

// this fields will be ignored:
'base_price_amount' =>1,
'base_price_base_amount'=>1,
'base_price_base_unit' => 'PCS',
'base_price_unit' => 'PCS',
```

Comment: This should work. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't. Perhaps you can try to clear cache completely (again)? Attributes sometimes can't be used after a module has been installed / created, before clearing cache completely (i.e. remove `var/cache`).